# Finding XML (SVG) child elements

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, svg, nsxmlparser

I have the following SVG

```
<g id="background">
    <rect style="fill:#2A6683;" width="768" height="1024"/>
</g>
<g id="wall">
    <rect x="352" y="457" style="fill:#25436B;" width="64" height="64"/>
</g>
<g id="hole">
    <circle style="fill:#25436B;" cx="384" cy="73.06" r="32"/>
</g>
<g id="dot">
    <circle style="fill:#FFFFFF;" cx="384" cy="945.557" r="32"/>
</g>
```

What I'd like to do is look at the `g element id` so I know what type of object it is and then 
at the `child element` of the `g` element to know the properties of the object. 
I know how to parse the svg file using `NSXMLParser`, the problem is that I don't know how to access the child elements with reference to the `g` element.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"g"]) {
        NSString *object = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"id"];

        if ([object isEqualToString:@"wall"]) {
            // look at the child element for position value etc...
        } else if ([object isEqualToString:@"dot"])  {
           // look at the child element for position value etc...
        }else if ([object isEqualToString:@"hole"]) {
          // look at the child element for position value etc...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can use XPath, you could use `//g[@id="background"]/*` to select all children of a particular ID.

Answer (score 0):

This should work,or at least it worked for me.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:     (NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

  if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"g"]) {
    NSString *object = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"id"];

    if ([object isEqualToString:@"wall"]) {
      int width = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"width"];
      int height = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"height"];
    } else if ([object isEqualToString:@"dot"])  {
      int width = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"width"];
      int height = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"height"];
      // look at the child element for position value etc...
    }else if ([object isEqualToString:@"hole"]) {
      int width = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"width"];
      int height = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"height"];
      // look at the child element for position value etc...
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: thank you for your answer but I did try this before and does not work. `width` and `height` are `(null)`